# Is it possible to have both (for instance) /posts and /posts/:id?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I`m using react-router and I want to know that how is it possible to have both routes like: x.com/posts and x.com/posts/3

in the /posts route I want to show all the post list, and in the /posts/3 i want to show the details of a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! it is possible. check this explanation from [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/primary-components):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        {/* If the current URL is /about, this route is rendered
            while the rest are ignored */}
        <Route path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>

        {/* Note how these two routes are ordered. The more specific
            path="/contact/:id" comes before path="/contact" so that
            route will render when viewing an individual contact */}
        <Route path="/contact/:id">
          <Contact />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/contact">
          <AllContacts />
        </Route>

        {/* If none of the previous routes render anything,
            this route acts as a fallback.

            Important: A route with path="/" will *always* match
            the URL because all URLs begin with a /. So that's
            why we put this one last of all */}
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```